# Oracle BPM Authentication Service Error

Tags: oracle, soa, business-process-management

Recently I have installed and configured the Oracle BPM Suit and able to access **Oracle Business Process Composer** using the link as mentioned below

```
 http://localhost:7001/bpm/composer/
```

But sometimes it take too long time to enter me to the dashboard and shows **"Authentication Service Error, please contact the Administrator"**.

I have done the windows environment setup.

I have checked my credentials and sometimes it allows me to enter but sometimes this annoying message comes to me. I don't know what's wrong with the authentication service. I'll be grateful for any help/recommendation.

Comment: I don't find the exact reason of this problem but this was automatically fixed by re-starting the weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem, here are some suggestions:

- Remove DOMAIN and create another, remembering that everything will be lost;
- Create another user WebLogic;
- If you want to solve the problem look for logs on WebLogic or in the DOMAIN directory, to understand the problem;

Recently consultants ORACLE were here on business and found that the 12c version is not stable. Look for patches on the Oracle website.